# Does MS's WebsiteSpark include Windows 7 downloads?

Tags: windows, msdn, websitespark

We are a Linux/Mac shop, being asked to do some .NET coding. We've got a couple licenses lying around for XP that we use to test out sites in IE.

We are thinking we might want to get some boxes with full blown Windows 7, so we can install VS2010 and all the snazzy tools.

From the website, it seems like WebsiteSpark includes a subscription to MSDN. And MSDN includes software downloads, including Windows 7 Pro or Ultimate, right?

Answer (score 1):

No, WebsiteSpark does not come with Windows 7, currently you can only get Windows Server 2008 and Windows Server 2008 R2.